# Which efficient & portable shell statement on GNU/Linux can zero-pad piped bytes to word boundary?

Tags: shell, pipe, posix, padding

I need to pad NUL bytes at the end of a byte stream exceeding available storage & memory, so output length is divisible by N. Context of the function I am implementing:

```bash
#!/bin/sh
generate_arbitrary_length | paddingN | work_with_padded
```

Working code for N=8192:

```bash
padding8192(){ dd status=none bs=8192 conv=sync ; }
```

But reducing copy block size is *orders of magnitude* slower for small N, this did not finish:

```bash
padding4(){ dd status=none bs=4 conv=sync ; }
```

I can express the counting & padding using `wc` and `dd`, after duplicating the input stream:

```bash
padding4(){ { { tee /dev/fd/3 >&2 ; } 3>&1 | wc -c | { read -r isize ; pad=$(( 4 - isize % 4)) ; [ 0 -lt $pad ] && dd status=none if=/dev/zero bs=$pad count=1 >&2 ; } } 2>&1 ; }
```

Much faster already. But very difficult to read - who could even tell why padding ends up at EOF?

Any better approach?

Though I only need to keep as much state as needed to store byte count modulo word size, I cannot think of a simple yet performant implementation using shell builtins. Dependencies should remain minimal: using GNU coreutils/cpio/tar, no compiler/perl/features that would differ between busybox/dash/bash. I have not come up with an `awk` solution as I failed to make it perform well (G/s) on binary input not evenly NL/NUL-separated into lines.

Comment: `In a minimal Linux environment` How minimal? What environment exactly? `POSIX shell` Which shell exactly? `Any better approach` Use awk. Which awk version do you have exactly? Download statically linked perl and do it in perl. Write a C code with the functionality, cross compile and run it.

Comment: @KamilCuk Thats what I am trying to avoid. Would be so much better to keep it as a script that just works, even on architectures I have barely even heard of. Currently testing against environments where `awk` is provided by busybox (1.27+) or gawk (5.1.0+).

Comment: `I can express the counting & padding using wc and dd, after duplicating the input stream` The code will not work, `isize` is assigned in a subshell as part of the pipeline, its value is lost. Also `wc -l` you are counting lines (??) not bytes.

Comment: @KamilCuk sorry, [manual mistake](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75490665/revisions) introduced while stripping down to minimal demo.

Answer (score 1):

Since you mention there's a compiler available, here's a tiny, portable C program. It does not get any faster and memory-economic. It's even readable for most people in the programming community. If not, you can always sprinkle `/* Comments! */`. :-)

```
#!/bin/sh
#
# pad.sh - pad input, reading in large blocks from stdin, writing stdout.

# padding $1:padchar $2:alignment $3:blocksize
padding () {
aout="./a$$.out"
cc -x c -o "$aout" - <<EOF
#include <stdio.h>

int main (void) {
  size_t align = $2, nwritten = 0, nread;
  char buffer[$3];
  while ((nread = fread (buffer, 1, sizeof buffer, stdin)) > 0)
    nwritten += fwrite (buffer, 1, nread, stdout);
  if ((nwritten % align) != 0)
    for (align -= nwritten % align; align != 0; --align)
      putchar ($1);
  return 0;
}
EOF
"$aout" && rm "$aout"
}

printf '%s' 123456789 | padding 0       4 16384                  | od -c
printf '%s' abcdefghi | padding "'\n'" 16 BUFSIZ                 | od -c
printf '%s' PAGE_SIZE | padding 65     32 "$(getconf PAGE_SIZE)" | od -c
```

In action:

```
$ ./pad.sh
0000000    1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9  \0  \0  \0
0000014
0000000    a   b   c   d   e   f   g   h   i  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n  \n
0000020
0000000    P   A   G   E   _   S   I   Z   E   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
0000020    A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A   A
0000040
```

If you are concerned about the non-POSIXly compiler option `-x c` you can easily write the C program to `pad.c` and compile it from there. Advanced error handling for `fwrite`, `fread` and `putchar` left to the reader.

Note how the here-document avoids main having to parse arguments. You can even pass strings like PAGE_SIZE if your stdio makes them available by default.

I just realized that compiling C like this is not much different from a nifty awk script -- awk also compiles an internal program and then executes it. What's better than compiling to the machine's CPU and running the executable?

Answer (score 0):

The POSIX thing to do would be to use a temporary file.

```
padding() (
   tmpf=$(mktemp) &&
   trap 'rm "$tmpf"' EXIT &&
   tee "$tmpf" &&
   isize=$(wc -c <"$tmpf") &&
   pad=$(( $1 - isize % $1 )) &&
   if [ "$pad" -ne 0 ]; then
       dd status=none if=/dev/zero bs="$pad" count=1
   fi
)
```

Comment: Only works if input size <= storage. Need to run it in parallel, only buffering pipe size.